# Will Terminal Services Audio Recording Redirection work across a standard broadband connection?

Tags: audio, terminal-services

We're looking at setting up some software on Terminal Services, but need to redirect audio recording to the server for this software to fulfil its function.

The Terminal Services servers are hosted 'in the cloud' (i.e. I don't know where), and will be accessed across standard UK broadband connections (anything from 2-3mbps symmetrical, through to 'up to' 8mbps ADSL).

Does anyone have any experience of this, or know where I can find documentation on minimum baselines for bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Terminal Services much, but I am with audio. CD-quality audio is sampled at 44.1khz, is 16-bit and stereo. This much information takes up 176KB/sec. This is less than 1.5mbps (megabits per second). So if that is the quality parameters of your audio recording, you should be fine. Note that this takes no networking overhead into account, but that should be negligible.